# How to perform cell-based calculations on multidimensional raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator

I have a large multi-dimensional raster with 500 bands derived from a raster stack in R. I want to do some arithmetic operations to each element in each band. The specific operation is x/(1-x). Whenever I try this operation in ArcGIS Pro, it will only use the first band.

I have tried both with the Raster Calculator available through the spatial analyst package, and the Calculator through raster functions -> math functions. I have played around with the 'multidimensional data' settings in the Calculator function, but nothing yields an outputted multidimensional raster

Comment: In ArcGIS Desktop I would use python, set the current workspace to the raster and then iterate the bands using arcpy.ListRasters(), there is a Pro version https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listrasters.htm which should list all your bands. Each band will output to a single raster so use composite bands to restack them https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/raster-functions/composite-bands-function.htm hope that helps.

Comment: @MichaelStimson thanks for the suggestion, worked great!